# How to identify a ENTER keypress on a node in CTreeCtrl in VC++?

Tags: visual-c++, tree, enter

I am trying to perform something on an Enter key press on a tree view node. At present I am only able to detect mouse double click as it sends 'NM_DBLCLK' message after double clicking on the node.Is there any similar message sent on pressing ENTER key on the node? or is there any way to identify ENTER keypress?
This is in VC++ IDE.
Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: Are you looking for `NM_RETURN` notification?

Comment: I tried using that, but an 'ENTER' press doesn't return 'NM_RETURN' notification i guess.

Comment: I figured out that we can identify ENTER keypress by checking for VK_RETURN condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that we can identify ENTER key press by checking for VK_RETURN condition.